# numpy - Sum of dot products along axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I have an `A` x `B` array and another `D` x `A` x `A` array and am trying to come up with efficient ways to compute the sum of the dot products of two arrays along the `D` axis (such that the result would be an `A` x `B` array). The most obvious way would be to use a for loop:

```
result = np.zeros(first_array.shape)
for d in range(0,second_array.shape[0]):
    result = result + np.dot(second_array[d], first_array)
print result
```

I'm wondering if there are more efficient ways of computing this in numpy. I've read a bit  into [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) but unfortunately don't completely understand whether it would be able to help in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [436]: np.einsum('ijk,km->jm',np.ones((2,3,3)),np.ones((3,4)))
Out[436]: 
array([[ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
       [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.],
       [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.]])
In [437]: _.shape
Out[437]: (3, 4)
```

Your `dot` is expressed as (`k` shared between last of first and 2nd to last of 2nd):

```
In [438]: np.einsum('jk,km->jm',np.ones((3,3)),np.ones((3,4)))
Out[438]: 
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

Adding `i` to the first array matches its 3d shape.  But omitting it from the `result` tells `einsum` to sum its values.  Without the summing

```
In [439]: np.einsum('ijk,km->ijm',np.ones((2,3,3)),np.ones((3,4))).shape
Out[439]: (2, 3, 4)
```